# SSIS Adding And expression on An Excel connection manager

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I've been trying to create an Expression IN SSIS On an Excel connection manager for 2 days now and i havent been successful till now. i've tried to set the delayValidation to TRUE AND FALSE But it won't work. below is the error message that it keeps giving me all the times that i've tried.

> Package Validation Error (Package Validation Error)
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Source [20]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed. Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: Excel Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C. Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation. Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.  (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)
>
> Program Location:    at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.ValidateAndRunDebugger(Int32 flags, IOutputWindow outputWindow, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)    at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DtsPackagesFolderProjectFeature.ExecuteTaskOrPackage(ProjectItem prjItem, String taskPath)

I will be very grateful if someone can help me out with it.

Comment: What is the expression? The property you are assigning the expression to it?